# Rank of a matrix of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, binomial-coefficients, finite-fields

This question arose as a side computation on error correcting codes.
Let $k$, $r$ be positive integers such that $2k-1 \leqslant r$ and let $p$ a prime number such that $r < p$. I would like to find the rank of the following $k \times k$ matrix with coefficients in the field $F_p$ 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\binom {r}{k} & \binom {r}{k+1} & \dotsm & \binom {r}{2k-1}\\
\vdots & \\
\binom {r}{2} & \binom {r}{3} & \dotsm & \binom {r}{k+1} \\
\binom {r}{1} & \binom {r}{2} & \dotsm & \binom {r}{k} 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where all binomial coefficients are taken modulo $p$. I conjecture the rank should be $k$ but I have no formal proof. I am aware of [Lucas's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem), but it didn't help so far.

Comment: No good news for you anyway :(

Comment: I think that you need $r+k\le p$ (instead of $r<p$) to get full rank. Otherwise you run into the problem in zhoraster's answer. I did a bit of testing, and this seems to check out. I have a vague recollection of somebody (robjohn?) handling a similar problem once...

Comment: @jyrki-lahtonen This would be a nice way to save my conjecture. Let me know if you remember the reference you mention or if you can prove the result in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Not true, unfortunately.

Indeed, by adding the $2$nd row to the $1$st, $3$rd to $2$nd, ... , $k$th to $(k-1)$th etc, you end up with the matrix 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\binom {r+1}{k} & \binom {r+1}{k+1} & \dotsm & \binom {r+1}{2k-1}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
\binom {r+1}{2} & \binom {r+1}{3} & \dotsm & \binom {r+1}{k+1} \\
\binom {r}{1} & \binom {r}{2} & \dotsm & \binom {r}{k} 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which has the same rank.

In particular, for $r=p-1$ we get $\pmod p$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & \dotsm & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
0 & 0 & \dotsm & 0 \\
* & * & \dotsm & *
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
I doubt this has rank $k$.

Moreover, it is easy to see with this argument that the rank is at most $p-r$.

---

Update: For $k\ge p-r$, the rank is exactly $p-r$. Sketch: make the above transformations with first $k-1$ rows, then with first $k-2$ rows, etc. Then do the same to columns. You will end up with 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\binom {r+k-1}{k} & \binom {r+k}{k+1} & \dotsm & \binom {r+2k-2}{2k-1}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
\binom {r+2}{3} & \binom {r+3}{4} & \dotsm & \binom {r+k+1}{k+2} \\
\binom {r+1}{2} & \binom {r+2}{3} & \dotsm & \binom {r+k}{k+1} \\
\binom {r}{1} & \binom {r+1}{2} & \dotsm & \binom {r+k-1}{k} 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now $\pmod p$ the non-zero elements of this matrix form a lower-left triangle of size $p-r$ (I hope this is clear, as I don't know how LaTeX such thing). Hence, the rank is $p-r$.

It is also possible to do this for $k>p-r$, which gives only lower bound $2p-2r-k$ for the rank;  not a lot of help, probably.

Comment: Thank you for your very nice answer. Do you think that the conjecture might be true for $r+k \leqslant p$, according to the comment of Jyrki Lahtonen?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin, does not seem likely to me.

Answer (score 4):

Write $A(r,k)$ for the matrix you describe. Then
$$
\det A(r,k) =\prod_{i,j=1}^k \frac{r-k-1+i+j}{i+j-1}.
$$
This follows from equation (2.17) in Krattenthaler's [*Advanced determinant calculus*](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9902004) (with $a=n=k$, $b=r-k$). For $p\geq r+k$ every factor in the product has numerator coprime to $p$, so the reduction of $A(r,k)$ has full rank.

Comment: So it seems from this formula that $M(r,k)$ can be written nicely as a product of two matrices, whose determinants are easily computed.

Comment: This formula can be rewritten as 
$$
\frac{\prod_{j=1}^k (j-1)! (r-1+j)!}{\prod_{j=1}^k (r-k-1 +j)! (k-1+j)!}.
$$
In this form, it seems very likely to be true. I would love to see a proof.

Comment: Yet one equivalent form: 
$$
\prod_{j=1}^k \frac{r-1+j\choose k}{k-1+j\choose k}.
$$

Comment: Fantastic finding!

Comment: I remembered seeing [this post on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/219196/on-determinants-formed-by-binomial-coefficients/) that used a formula from Krattenthaler's paper.

Comment: Open problem: which answer should I accept?? Both answers are great !